# SSL Exceptions while sending https request from my grails web application deployed in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am getting following Exception when HTTPS Request is sent from Grails Web Application deployed in Tomcat Server(8):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Here is When I make HTTPS Call(On which Point I get this Exception):

```
String URL = "https://**.**.**.**:8440/*****";
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(URL);
client.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

I have created the keystore file using keytool command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

and changed the server.xml file too of Tomcat but still getting this exception. Here is my Server.XML File:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
           port="443" keystoreFile="/keystore/keystore.jks" keystorePass="password" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />   

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

I have gone through the following possible fixes for this but no luck:

1. http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes
2. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/tomcat-ssl-howto.html
3. http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/ssl-howto.html

P.S. I simply want tomcat to allow my application to hit HTTPS request for the URL:

```
 String URL = "https://**.**.**.**:8440/*****";
```

I am rolling my head on this but unfortunately not getting through. Please guide me that what could be the fix for this ? Or I am doing anything wrong ?
Thanks for Your Time :)

Comment: Is it a self signed SSL certificate?

Comment: To be fair, I don't have details knowledge of about keystores and certificates. Though I got certificate(.cer) file from browser by hitting this URL and Keystore file by keytool command (keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA). I think it's self signed

Comment: I have verified that Tomcat is accessing keystore file and also validating password but still its ridiculous to me why It's not allowing HTTPS Calls from inside my application.

Comment: Does this exception occur on the server or on the client side? It is not very clear out of the question you asked.

Comment: I'd recommend checking your installed cert with: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Comment: This Applications works fine when I run this locally in IntelliJ. But When I deploy this application on Tomcat I start getting this exception as my application tries to hit HTTPS URL. It's server side.

Comment: If you have valid certificate try to import that in the cacerts of java keystore to which tomcat is pointing . It should work

Comment: Okay ... Please tell me one thing if I am using secured API(HTTPS Based) then how may I get valid certificate for that ?
As for now I am generating keystore file using keytool

Comment: Some certicate you can get it from browser IE itself. Some certificate you have to use some tools. I dont have an idea about tools. Please refer below link to get from IE  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/import-export-certificates-private-keys#1TC=windows-7

Comment: this also might useful http://www.margi.marnet.net.mk/CA/certexport-ie.html

Comment: I have certificate for this and have added in java too. this whole works alright locally which means that certificate I added is correct and working fine. But when I deploy this application on tomcat server then it issues :( Will we have to add this certificate separately in tomcat ? While it should get this from java installed